# setting $NODE in ubuntu

Tags: environment-variables, nodejs, npm

I've been trying to install a javascript framework using npm and it fails at the following command:

```
$NODE make/index.js call_npm=false parallel=true build=release all
```

The environment variable *$NODE* is not set on my System. The command *which node* returns:

```
/usr/bin/node
```

I'm assuming that I somehow have to (permanently) add the environment variable using this path, but I can't figure out how. Please Help. Thank you.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022742/setting-node-env-for-node-js-expressjs-application-as-a-daemon-under-ubuntu) helps

Comment: Or [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables).